# Need Proper Syntax for Condition (wrap Image with link only when there is one)

Tags: php, wordpress

we had a developer code something for a Custom Post Type in WordPress that we need to tweak just a touch. They're not available right now, but I think it's a pretty simple PHP issue if knowing the proper syntax. Unfortunately, I'm not completely PHP fluent, so hoping to get some help.

We have a posts landing page where we are just displaying a post thumbnail if there is one, and a link to the full post page (single) ONLY if an email address has been entered into the custom post type. If no email address was entered for the post, no link to the final post. Here's the main chunk of code that is currently working properly for this:

```
$team_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($team_query->have_posts()) {
    $team_query->the_post();
    $member_email = get_post_meta(
        get_the_ID(), '_base_team_email', true
    );

    $html .= '<div class="span-6 team-member">';

    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $html .= '<div class="member-photo-wrap">'
            . get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'medium')
            . '</div>';
    }

    if (!empty($member_email)) {
        $html .= '<p class="member-email">'
            . '<a class="linkIcon" href="' . get_permalink() . '#member-top">'
            . 'Email &amp; Bio &raquo;'
            . '</a></p>';
    }

    $html .= '</div>';
}
```

All we need to do is tweak so that IF an email address has been entered, the same hyperlink is added around the thumbnail image so it can link to the final post along with the 'Email & Bio' text link. But if NO email address is found, the thumbnail image displays as-is (e.g, no link added).

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would add a link to the thumbnail as well, if the `$member_email` is not empty.

```
$team_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($team_query->have_posts()) {
    $team_query->the_post();
    $member_email = get_post_meta(
        get_the_ID(), '_base_team_email', true
    );

    // Create anchor tag to use when member email is not empty 
    $memberEmailAnchorStart = '';
    $memberEmailAnchorEnd   = '';

    if (!empty($member_email)) {
        $memberEmailAnchorStart =
            '<a class="linkIcon" href="' . get_permalink() . '#member-top">';
        $memberEmailAnchorEnd = '</a>';
    }

    $html .= '<div class="span-6 team-member">';

    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $html .= '<div class="member-photo-wrap">'
            . $memberEmailAnchorStart
            . get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'medium')
            . $memberEmailAnchorEnd
            . '</div>';
    }

    if (!empty($member_email)) {
        $html .= '<p class="member-email">'
            . $memberEmailAnchorStart
            . 'Email &amp; Bio &raquo;'
            . $memberEmailAnchorEnd
            . '</p>';
    }

    $html .= '</div>';
}
```

Depending on what the `linkIcon` class does, you might want to remove it from the thumbnail anchor tag.